# Grafana stops showing prometheus data when label values have certain format

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a prometheus exporter which is being scraped by Prometheus 2.44.0 Server, this is being written into Amazon Managed Service for Prometheus. I am then consuming the AWS Managed Service for Prometheus with Amazon Managed Grafana (Grafana version 9.4).

When my prometheus exporter is producing series which include this series:

```
org_exist_management_exist_processreport_runningqueries_elapsed{key_id="1406887263",key_key="String/2240389879743818120",} 144429.0
```

then all works well and I see this reflected in my Grafana Dashboard. Yay! So far so good :-)

However, if my prometheus exporter produces series which include series like this:

```
org_exist_management_exist_processreport_runningqueries_elapsed{key_id="6835586",key_key="/db/query1.xq",} 45123.0
```

then my Grafana dashboard stops updating with any data until the prometheus exporter stops producing such series. The only difference I can see between the two series is the format of the value of the Label named `key_key`, i.e. `String/2240389879743818120` vs. `/db/query1.xq`.

Is there some limitation on valid characters that can be placed inside a Label's value with Prometheus/Grafana?

If not, how do I start figuring out where the problem lies, my prometheus exporter seems happy enough and I can check its `/metrics` end-point via cURL, but how can I work out if the issue after that is Prometheus Server or Grafana?

Comment: Have you checked Prometheus' Web console? Is your "problematic" metric visible there?

Comment: "my Grafana dashboard stops updating with any data" this is regarding only panel where said metric is involved, or all panels of the dashboard? If former, what query is used on said panel?

Comment: @markalex all panels on the Dashboard stop updating. Apologies, but I am rather new to Prometheus, where would I find the Web Console?

Comment: On your prometheus server. For local installations address would look something like localhost:9090. It should look something like [this](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph)